# Two points of a vector

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a source point of a vector (x, y), the vector's size, and the angle of it.
What's the formula to calculate the X and Y values of the point the vector will get to from the source point?
I tried:
  X: size * cos(angle)
  Y: size * sin(angle)

And it doesn't seem to be right.

Thanks a lot for all helpers.

Comment: What do you mean by "the angle of it"? Is that the angle that the vector makes with the x-axis?  Also, what do you mean by the "source-point" of the vector?

Comment: Yes, and the point the vector starts from on a 2d Cartesian coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are measuring your angle, $\theta$, relative to the $\hat{x}$ direction (or $x$ axis), perhaps you are calling it the $\hat{i}$ direction. What you are asking here is where is the new point given a starting point $(x_0,y_0)$ and a displacement vector $\vec{\mathbf{v}}=(v_x,v_y)$. The new point, $(x,y)$ will be
$$
(x,y)=\left(x_0+v_x,y_0+v_y\right)
$$
That is, $x=x_0+v_x$ and $y=y_0+v_y$. In terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ of the given displacement vector, $\vec{\mathbf{v}}$, the answer would be
$$
(x,y)=\left(x_0+\|v\|\cos \theta ,y_0+\|v\|\sin \theta \right)
$$
or $x=x_0+\|v\|\cos \theta$ and $y=y_0+\|v\|\sin \theta$, where $\|v\|$ is the magnitude or length of your given displacement vector $\vec{\mathbf{v}}$ and $\theta$ is the angle of your displacement vector $\vec{\mathbf{v}}$ relative to the $\hat{x}$ direction.